# How to have multiple WCF service endpoints when implementing more than one contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, service, endpoint

Here is my service class which implements everything :

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class RESTservice : IRESTservice, IRESTservice2
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    int personCount = 0;

    public Person CreatePerson(Person createPerson)
    {
        createPerson.ID = (++personCount).ToString();
        persons.Add(createPerson);
        return createPerson;
    }

    public List<Person> GetAllPerson()
    {
        return persons.ToList();
    }

    public List<Person> GetAllPerson2()
    {
        return persons.ToList();
    }

    public Person GetAPerson(string id)
    {
        return persons.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
    }

    public Person UpdatePerson(string id, Person updatePerson)
    {
        Person p = persons.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
        p.Name = updatePerson.Name;
        p.Age = updatePerson.Age;
        return p;
    }

    public void DeletePerson(string id)
    {
        persons.RemoveAll(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

(Both contracts are working fine)

Here is my web. config file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <services>
          <service name="RESTservice">
            <endpoint address="RestService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="test.IRESTservice" />
            <endpoint address="RestService2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="test.IRESTservice2" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
      </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

and of course my service declaration :

```
     RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RestService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(RESTservice)));
```

I am getting the following exception when doing an http GET on localhost:port/RestService :

Service 'RESTservice' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can set up default endpoints, but only if the service implements only a single ServiceContract. Either change the service to only implement a single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service explicitly in the configuration file.

I have no idea what has gone wrong. Any leads ?

Answer (score 1):

Both IRESTservice and IRESTservice2 declaration must have ServiceContractAttribute ConfigurationName set to same name as in your config file:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="test.IRESTservice")
public interface IRESTService
{
}

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="test.IRESTservice2")
public interface IRESTService2
{
}
```

Comment: It says I cannot use "ServiceContractAttribute" twice (even if in different interfaces) so I decorated with this instead : [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "test.IRESTservice")] and [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "test.IRESTservice2")] but I still get the same exception

Comment: With your solution I get the folowing compilation error : "Error 1 Duplicate 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute'"